# How to manipulate 3 DataStream in on Flink job?

Tags: apache-flink

We have 3 java pojos,

```
class Foo{
 int id;
 String name;
 List<Bar1> list1;
 List<Bar2> list2;
}

class Bar1{
 int id;
 String field_x;
 String field_y;
}

class Bar2{
 int id;
 String field_a;
 String field_b;
}
```

And we have 3 DataStreams in our Flink job,

```
class Test{
 public static void main(...){
  DataStream<Foo> ds1 = ...;
  DataStream<Bar1> ds2 = ...;
  DataStream<Bar2> ds3 = ...;
 }
}
```

For each id, there will be only one Foo object, while Bar1 and Bar2 object could be multiple.

What we want to do is, for each Foo in ds1, find all Bar1 with the same id in ds2 and put them into list1, find all Bar2 with the same id in ds3 and put them into list2.

What is the best way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink's DataStream operators support up to two input streams. 
There are two common ways to implement operations on three streams:

1. with two binary operations. This is very simple in your case since `Bar1` and `Bar2` are not related to each other. This would look roughly as follows:

```java
DataStream<Foo> withList1 = ds1
  .connect(ds2).keyBy("id", "id")
  .process(
    // your processing logic
    new CoProcessFunction<Foo, Bar1, Foo>(){...});
DataStream<Foo> withList1AndList2 = withList1
  .connect(ds3).keyBy("id", "id")
  .process(
    // your processing logic
    new CoProcessFunction<Foo, Bar2, Foo>(){...});
```

2. by unioning all three streams into a single stream with a common data type (for example a POJO with three fields `foo`, `bar1`, and `bar2` of which only one field is used and using an operator with a single input to process the unioned stream.

```java
// map Foo to CommonType
DataStream<CommonType> common1 = ds1.map(new MapFunction<Foo, CommonType>(){...}); 
// map Bar1 to CommonType
DataStream<CommonType> common2 = ds2.map(new MapFunction<Bar1, CommonType>(){...});
// map Bar2 to CommonType
DataStream<CommonType> common3 = ds3.map(new MapFunction<Bar2, CommonType>(){...});

DataStream<Foo> withList1AndList2 = ds1.union(ds2, ds3)
  .keyBy("id")
  .process(
    // your processing logic
    new KeyedProcessFunction<CommonType, Foo>(){...});
```

You can also just union `ds2` and `ds3` and use a binary operator.

The bigger problem might be to identify when all `Bar1` and `Bar2` events were received such that you can emit a result. Again, there a few options (depending on your use case).

1. if `Foo` knows for how many `Bar1` and `Bar2` it needs to wait, the solution is obvious.
2. if `Foo` does not know for how many events to wait, you can try to send a notification that signals that the last `Bar1` or `Bar2` was sent.
3. you can also work with a time out if you know that all `Bar1` or `Bar2` should arrive within x seconds/minutes/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I'm quite new to Flink, is it possible for you to provide a code snippet, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I've added some snippets to make the overall flow clear

Comment: Hi Fabian, I still have trouble writing the "process(...)". I have figured out how to do that when having a time window, since it has an iterator, I can go through the iterator. But I have no idea what to do when there's no time window. Can you please help to give some example? (suppose that all Bar1 or Bar2 should arrive within 3 minutes). Many Thanks.

Comment: The idea is to use timers (via the `Context` object). When you receive a `Foo` object, you store it in state and register a timer 3 minutes in advance. Within these 3 minutes, you add all `Bar1` and `Bar2` objects to the `Foo` object, i.e., update the state. After 3 minutes, the timer calls the `onTimer()` callback method which emits the `Foo` object and clears the state.

Comment: Got it, I think I need to learn state relevant knowledge. Thank you again!